# What API / endpoints do I need to request access to retrieve LinkedIn company posts?

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to integrate my client's company LinkedIn posts into their website's social feed. I have created an app in the Linkedin Developers portal. I need help understanding which APIs/products to access for this purpose and whether there are restrictions for this usecase.

I've had a look through the documentation but can't seem to find clear instructions on:

1. The specific products/APIs to enable for accessing company posts that I need to request access to.
2. The precise endpoints required for retrieving these posts.
3. Additionally, I also came across an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/restricted-use-cases?view=li-lms-2023-10) that mentions social feeds are specifically an 'unapproved use case" for the Marketing API and I'm uncertain if it applies to my situation.

If someone could please provide clarity on the process and/or relevant documentation links, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!